# Add another object from a file to a Javascript Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

im trying to build a cart functionality where the user would add a **single** product to an array of products or objects.

```
  var product = {
                    "Name": "Bike",
                    "Price": "900",
                    "idproduct": "1"
                };
```

now i would like to store this product in plain json text.Stringify function does just that.

```
var JsonString = JSON.stringify(product);
```

Now i would like to take that JsonString and convert it back to an object or object array like so.

```
var JsonObjectArray  = JSON.parse(JsonString);
```

Now im going to create a new exactly the same json object type but with diff values.

```
var product2 = {
                    "Name": "Car",
                    "Price": "12000",
                    "idproduct": "2"
                };
```

It seems that JsonObjectArray doesnt have the push method because it got deserialized into a single object namely product1, what should i do so i can add 
product2 to JsonObjectArray as another member of the aray like so and repeat the process multiple times.

```
JsonObjectArray.push(product2);
```

Comment: Isn't push for arrays? You've got objects here right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with `product` as you have defined it, you will want to do one of the following:

- Use `JSON.stringify([product])` so that `JsonString` will be an JSON array:

  ```
  var JsonString = JSON.stringify([product]);
  var JsonObjectArray = JSON.parse(JsonString);
  ```
- Leave `JsonString` as a single object, but create a one element array from the result of `JSON.parse`:

  ```
  var JsonString = JSON.stringify(product);
  var JsonObjectArray = [JSON.parse(JsonString)];
  ```

Comment: I would define a `products` variable for clarity, and so you have access to the array without having to stringify and parse it.

Comment: May I request you to [vote to undelete this old answer please](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20844795/548225)